# Idle session "undefined" problem

Tags: control-panel, login

We just upgraded to EE 2.8.1 and both my client and I are having an issue where after our cp session times out we get the idle session modal and then we enter our password, click login and a browser dialog box comes up saying "undefined" and we can't login.  This is happing on chrome, safari and ff.

You can refresh to get back to the main login screen but it's kind of annoying.  Has anyone else seen this?

Thanks,

Jim

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem as well, it's very annoying.

There's a bug report here you might want to add to:
https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20374/undefined-alert-when-logging-in-to-expired-session